# Youtube Data API - Publish to Youtube Shorts

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

I'm using the following code to publish regular videos to Youtube.

Can I publish to Youtube Shorts using Youtube's Data API?

I've tried including #Shorts in the title and/or description as well varios categories Ids with no success.

Anyone managed to do it?

```
static async uploadVideo(auth, videoTitle, videoDescription, videoUrl, is_private,publishDate) {
    const youtube = google.youtube({ version: 'v3', auth });

    const status = {privacyStatus: is_private ? 'private' : 'public'};
    if (publishDate) {
      status.publishAt = publishDate
    }

    const videoMetadata = {
        snippet: {
            title: videoTitle || 'Default Video Title',
            description: videoDescription || 'Default Video Description',
            categoryId : '42'
        },
        status
    };

    const videoStream = await this.fetchVideoStream(videoUrl);
    if (videoStream) {
      const res = await youtube.videos.insert(
        {
            part: 'snippet,status',
            requestBody: videoMetadata,
            media: {
                body: videoStream,
            },
        },
        {
            onUploadProgress: (event) => {
                const progress = (event.bytesRead / event.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log(`Upload progress: ${progress.toFixed(2)}%`);
            },
        }
      );

      return {
          title: res.data.snippet.title,
          id: res.data.id,
      };
    }
    else {
      console.log('VIDEO STREAM FAILED',videoStream);
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube api predates YouTube shorts by more than ten years.   There is no way to tell it that you are uploading a short

Comment: So there's no way to upload a video directly to shorts via the API?

Comment: No there isn't but there a a few feature request for it